# Check Berkeley db version in windows

Tags: windows, berkeley-db

I have this error log :

> XBRLAPI Exception: The BDB XML database environment could not be set up.
>
> Caused by: DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch: Build signature doesn't match environment
>   org.xbrlapi.utilities.XBRLException:  XBRLAPI Exception: The BDB XML database environment could not be set up. ...
>
> Caused by: com.sleepycat.db.VersionMismatchException: DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch: Build signature doesn't match environment: DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch. ...

Anyone know how to check Berkeley db version installed in windows?
thanks